# Using lag function gives an atomic vector with all zeroes

Tags: r

I have trying to use "lag" function in base R to calculate rainfall accumulations for a 6-hr period. I have hourly rainfall, then I calculate cumulative rainfall using cumsum function and then I am using the lag function to calculate 6-hr accumulations as below.

```
Event_Data<-dbGetQuery(con, "select feature_id, TO_CHAR(datetime, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as DATE_TIME, value_ms as RAINFALL_IN from Rain_HOURLY")

Event_Data$cume<-cumsum(Event_Data$RAINFALL_IN)
Event_Data$six_hr<-Event_Data$cume-lag(Event_Data$cume, 6)
```

But the lag function gives me all zeroes and the structure of the data frame looks like this-

```
'data.frame':   169 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ feature_id      : num  80 80 80 80 80 ...
 $ DATE_TIME  : chr  "09/10/2017 00:00" "09/10/2017 01:00" "09/10/2017 02:00" "09/10/2017 03:00" ...
 $ RAINFALL_IN: num  0.251 0.09 0.017 0.071 0.016 0.01 0.136 0.651 0.185 0.072 ...
 $ cume : num  0.251 0.341 0.358 0.429 0.445 ...
 $ six_hr : atomic  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num  -23 145 1
```

This code has worked fine with several of my other projects but I have no clue why I am getting zeroes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I am just guessing but is it because of units mismatch? `cume` seems to be fraction but you're trying to subtract 6 from it, which results in negative time series which doesn't make sense. So R returns 0?

Comment: @bala83 : n=6, I am not trying to subtract 6 but the value from n-6 th row.

Comment: I am not using R that much right now, but it might be because you are not using `lag` in context of  a time-series data here. The behavior is quite different in such cases and the documentation is silent on the matter. I such cases you can use `Lag` from Hmisc package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a conflict with the `lag` function from other packages, that would explain why this code worked on other scripts but not on this one.

try `stats::lag` instead of just `lag` to enforce which package you want to use. (or `dplyr::lag` which seems to work better for me at east) ?

Comment: Thank you! dplyr::lag worked for me. I realized that in the other scripts, I was using the dplyr package and for some reason it just assumed that I was using the lag function from dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misconception about what `lag()` from the `stats` package does. It's returning zeros, because you're taking the full data for cumulative rainfall and then subtract it again. Check this small example for an illustration:

```
x <- 1:20
y <- lag(x,3) ;y
 #[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#attr(,"tsp")
#[1] -2 17  1
x-y     #x is a vector
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#attr(,"tsp")
#[1] -2 17  1
```

As you can see, `lag()` simply keeps the vector values and just adds a time series attribute with the values "starting time, ending time, frequency". Because you put in a vector, it used the default values "1, length(Event_Data$cume), 1" and subtracted the lag from the starting and ending time, which is 3 in the example and seemingly 24 in your code output (which doesn't fit the code input above it, btw).

The problem is that your vector doesn't have any time attribute assigned to it, so R doesn't know which the corresponding values of your data and lagged data are. Thus, it simply subtracts the vector values and adds the time attribute of the lagged variable. To fix this, you just need to assign times to `Event_Data$cume`, by converting it to a time-series object, i.e. try `Event_Data$six_hr<-as.numeric(ts(Event_Data$cume) - lag(ts(Event_Data$cume), 6))`

It works fine for the small example above:

```
x <- ts(1:20)
y <- lag(x,3)
x-y     #x is a ts
#Time Series:
#Start = 1 
#End = 17 
#Frequency = 1 
# [1] -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3
```

Comment: @ Eldioo: Thank you! I understand what you are saying but for some reason the same function was working with the other script and the the data frame I was using it with had the exact same attributes. I will make sure that I convert the data to a time series object, next time I use it. Thanks again!!